# Recovery of files deleted locally

Tags: windows, eclipse, svn, subclipse

I accidentally deleted a few files from my local copy, and it's been a long time (which means several updates have been made). But now it's beginning to bother me and it seems I can't get them back using SVN.

I am working with eclipse, in Windows XP. Also, I don't remember which files were deleted (I know at least one). I almost never commit anything, I am just monitoring.

So far I have tried on the whole project : Revert (There are no changes to rever), update to HEAD (I don't recover the lost files), replace with latest from Repository (I don't recover the lost files).

What can I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can restore those files from Eclipse *Local History* provided it is enabled in your settings.

[Restoring from local history](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-restore-deleted-files-in-eclipse.html)

[Eclipse help on this matter](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-87b.htm)

The question is: Have you created those deleted files by yourself?

If so, Local history is your last stand, but I wouldn't get too excited beacause default Eclipse setting for *Days to keep files* is 7.

Comment: Sadly, it is not enabled in my settings. Also, I didn't create the files I deleted.